# PHP SQL Form Insert

Tags: php, sql

I've developed a form that inserts many things into the database. But somehow, when the page is filled up, it inserts only the user_password that too of the database admin. How can I resolve this problem?

```
<?php
//include the connection file

require_once('connection.php');
require_once("validation.php");

if( isset($_POST['send']) && (!validateName($_POST['name']) || !validateEmail($_POST['email']) || !validatePasswords($_POST['pass1'], $_POST['pass2']) || !validateContact($_POST['contact']) || !validateAge($_POST['age'])) ):?>
            <div id="error">    
                <ul>
                    <?php if(!validateName($_POST['name'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Invalid Name:</strong> We want names with more than 3 letters.</li>
                    <?php endif?>
                    <?php if(!validateEmail($_POST['email'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Invalid E-mail:</strong> Type a valid e-mail please.</li>
                    <?php endif?>
                    <?php if(!validatePasswords($_POST['pass1'], $_POST['pass2'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Passwords are invalid:</strong> Passwords doesnt match or are invalid!</li>
                    <?php endif?>
                    <?php if(!validateContact($_POST['contact'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Please enter your contact number.</strong></li>
                    <?php endif?>
                    <?php if(!validateAge($_POST['age'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Please enter your age</strong></li>
                    <?php endif?>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        <?php elseif(isset($_POST['send'])):?>
            <div id="error" class="valid">
                <ul>
                <?php $query = "INSERT INTO employee (name, password, email, contact, age, gender, location, skill) ";                           
                $query .= "('$name', '$password', '$email','$contact','$age','$gender','$location','$skill')";
                // run the query
                mysql_query($query);?>
                    <li><strong>Congratulations!</strong> All fields are OK ;)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php endif?>
```

Comment: there was some problem i guess. I'll again add it and give you the link.

Comment: When you need to insert a code just hit an enter and put 4 spaces before each code line...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SQL Form validation\[urgent\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840669/php-sql-form-validationurgent)

Comment: @pcsi: Please don't downvote my post. I forgot to paste it by pressing "Ctlr+V" in a hurry.

Comment: @Ecko but I didn't downvote your post man.

Comment: @pcsi: Okay. I don't know who did it. I have 34 reputation still I don't know why SO is not allowing me to post questions.:((

Comment: @Ecko, I know why. Did you read the link you're pointed at when you attempt to post questions?

Comment: Yes, I've read it over and over again. Will I be unbanned ever? As in the last 4-5 hours I've made my reputation by editing my answers and replies from 1 to 34. Still the same.

Comment: @Ecko I`ll give you a voteup to help buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forgot to pass the keyword "VALUES". Check the syntax for INSERT INTO.
2. The variables you are passing to MySQL ('$name', '$password', '$email','$contact','$age','$gender','$location','$skill') has not been set (they don't have a value).
3. You are not handling the case of null strings.
4. You should only call the database if you have validated ALL the parameters (you may have a SQL injection vulnerability*).
5. If you are learning PHP, I would recomend against using double quotes.
6. It may be better to separate output from logic, it will be more maintainable later.
7. There are libraries for this.

*: you may want to scape some characters too, there are functions in PHP for this, such as htmlentities and mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: I was learning PHP-SQL. So, was just trying to write codes from searching from different sources.

Comment: @PrateekSachan edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look up about these issues and try fixing them. If I'm unable to do it; please try helping me.

Comment: 1 more help: The result: "Congratulations! All fields are OK ;)"
appears in the top left corner of the page. I want to display it in the same page only just below the "submit" button.

Comment: @PrateekSachan if what you want is to have it appear without reloading the whole page, you will have to take a look into ajax (I would recommend to use jQuery for that). Otherwise just put this code (where you handle $_POST) in the same page where you have the form, in such way that the div with the mentioned  "Congratulations! All fields are OK ;)" would appear after the "submit" button as you say.

Comment: I was struggling with PHP a little while ago. But thanks to SO & you people. Thanks, I resolved it. :)

Comment: But please don't downvote the question". :(

Answer (score 1):

I've writted a complete code for you:

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table align="center">
  <tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Name:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" size="32" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Email:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="32" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Pass1:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="pass1" value="" size="32" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Contact:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="contact" value="" size="32" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Age:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="age" value="" size="32" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php require_once('../../../Connections/yourconnection.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO employee (id, name, email, pass1, contact, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['pass1'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['contact'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['age'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_yourdatabase, $databasename);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $databasename) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "sucess.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_yourdatabase, $databasename);
$query_query = "SELECT * FROM employee";
$query = mysql_query($query_query, $databasename) or die(mysql_error());
$row_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$totalRows_query = mysql_num_rows($query);

mysql_free_result($query);
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't checked out the form yet. I'll do it ASAP. By the way, I wrote a similar one earlier. But it couldn't validate anything. (It would take blank values as well and insert them in the table). So I tried browsing and came up with this one and modified it.